# How to make a repositionable 3x3 square in Swift, iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift (and iOS programming), and I ran into a problem:

I have a 3x3 area, with UIImageView-s in every cell.

Those have to be moveable, so upon dragging they have to chnage place. like this:

```
┌──┬──┬──┐  
│ 1│ 2│ 3│  
├──┼──┼──┤  
│ 4│ 5│ 6│  
├──┼──┼──┤  
│ 7│ 8│ 9│  
└──┴──┴──┘
```

dragging the first row to the right results in this:

```
┌──┬──┬──┐  
│ 3│ 1│ 2│  1,2,3 changed to 3,1,2
├──┼──┼──┤  
│ 4│ 5│ 6│  
├──┼──┼──┤  
│ 7│ 8│ 9│  
└──┴──┴──┘
```

How can I do this without or maybe with animation?

Comment: post what you tried first

Comment: i dont really have any parts done, just things like a 2d array with these numbers, the other is just the storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly to give an idea

```
var containerview = UIView() //set frame and color and stuff
var boxdata = [[UIImageView]]()

func viewdidload() {

    for index in 0..<3 {
        var row = [UIImageView]()
        for index in 0..<3 {
            println(index)
            var imageview = UIImageView() //set frame color image etc set so each iteration has a different frame..
            row.append(imageview)
            containerview.addSubview(imageview)
        }
        boxdata.append(row)
    }      
}

func swaplocations(first: UIImageView, second: UIImageView) {
 //swap frame of the 2 views and add animate with duration here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **UIAttachmentBehavior** class can be used to create a connection between two items or between an item and a point. You can use it by attaching a view to an anchor point and then add a Pan gesture to recognise drags on the screen while updating the attached view’s anchor point to where the user drags to.

You can use these Pan gestures to perform many different kinds of pans/animations. Here's one example that you can alter and edit to suit your kind of gesture for you app.

Drag a Pan Gesture Recognizer from the Object library to the view controller and create an action for the gesture recognizer by Control-dragging from the recognizer to the *AttachViewController.swift* file. Name the action handlePan and choose the type of action as **UIPanGestureRecognizer** instead of AnyObject.

It will contain code similar to this example. *Notice the squares are created programatically. But in your case you can just substitute with your UIViews. Of course you can name the ViewController class whatever you like.

Your app isn't using gravity but it's here anyway.

```
import UIKit

class AttachViewController: UIViewController {

var squareView: UIView!
var anchorView: UIView!
var attachment: UIAttachmentBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!

@IBAction func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    attachment.anchorPoint = sender.locationInView(view)
    anchorView.center = sender.locationInView(view)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view.addSubview(squareView)

    anchorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y, width: 20, height: 20))
    anchorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(anchorView)

    attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: squareView, attachedToAnchor: CGPointMake(anchorView.center.x, anchorView.center.y))

    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
    animator.addBehavior(attachment)

    gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```